# Mongoid accepts_nested_attributes_for saving parent when child is invalidwell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create a `User` during the creation of an `Organization`.  My problem is that the `Organization` is created (assuming it has valid information) even when the nested `User` information is invalid.

My models look like this:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document

  attr_accessible :name, :users_attributes

  field :name, :type => String

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :limit => 1

  validates_presence_of :name
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  field :email, type: String

  validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create 
  validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 6 }
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  belongs_to :organization
end
```

So basically, I pass in a valid organization and an invalid user.  The end result is that the organization is created properly despite the fact that the user information is invalid.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue here was that I wasn't specifying `:autosave => true` on my `has_many :users` association.  The end result was that it would create the organization and never attempt to save the associated user, thus not knowing it was invalid.  When i have the `:autosave` flag set to true and the user is invalid, the organization is not saved.